# Ajax post internal server error in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am new in ajax . I try to save data in database in Codeigniter framework using ajax. 
This is my ajax code:

```
  $('#cmpNameEditForm').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?=base_url();?>company/home/updateName',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                    'name': $('#cmpName').val(),
                },
            success: function(data) {
                $('p.error').html(data);
            }   
        });
    });
```

My view page is:-

```
<div id="name-edit-clone">
<?=form_open_multipart('', array('name'=>'CmpNameEditForm', 'role'=>'form', 'id'=>'cmpNameEditForm'))?>
<h3>Company Name</h3>
<?=form_input(array('name'=>'cmpName', 'id'=>'cmpName', 'placeholder'=>'Company Name', 'value'=>$company_name));?>
<?php echo form_error('cmpName','<p class="error">','</p>'); ?>
<?=form_submit(array('name'=>'submit', 'value'=>'Save', 'class'=>'btn btn-success nameSave'));?>
<?=form_button(array('name'=>'button', 'type'=>'reset', 'content'=>'Cancel' , 'class'=>'btn btn-danger nameCancel', 'id'=>'cmp-name-hide'));?>
<?=form_close()?>
</div>
```

What i am in wrong. Please help. Thanks you.

Comment: what error you got while calling ajax?

Comment: Try using site_url() instead of base_url()

Comment: Do you have mod rewrite enabled? If not, you may need to pass the data like `url: '<?=base_url();?>index.php/company/home/updateName'` or  `url: '<?=base_url();?>index.php?/company/home/updateName'`

Comment: when i calling ajax the message is 'Internal server error'.  I enable mode rewrite and i also used  site_url()

Comment: `company/home/updateName` this is your exact controller and function name?

Comment: Yes! company is folder name  home is a controller and updateName is my function name.   When i enable CSRF the error is 'The action you have requested is not allowed.'. but when i disable this is work fine.

Comment: post your controller code.

Comment: Controller Code:
public function updateName() {
    $lc = $this->session->userdata('logged_company');
    $company_id = $lc['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    if($this->profile_model->updateName($company_id, $name)) {
 echo $name;
    } 
}

My Model is

public function updateName($id, $name) {
        $data = array(
            'company_name' => $name
            );
       $this->db->where('company_id', $id);
       $query = $this->db->update('companies', $data);
       if($query) {
        return true;
       } else {
        return false;
       }
    }